# Would it be good Classical Latin style to always use the preposition "ab" and never "ā"?

Tags: classical-latin, preposition, style

I understand from *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata* (chap. 6) that the prepositions *ā* and *ab* are equivalent, except that *ā* is used only before words beginning with consonants, while *ab* can be used before any word, regardless of its initial letter.

Stylistically, in Classical Latin, would it be considered odd or incorrect to exclusively use *ab*?  Or, put another way, are there any Classical authors that completely neglect the use of *ā*?

Comment: As a single datapoint, Caesar doesn't shy from using ā in *De bello Gallico* - it's used in [the first paragraph of the first chapter of the first book.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Caes.+Gal.+1.1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0002)

Comment: Related: [Why “ex nihilo” instead of “e nihilo”?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2430/12)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe that would be considered very odd. Before certain words, *ab* is almost never used by any author. Consider for example [**ab te*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ab%20te%23), which is found 0 times in the Hewlett-Packard repository. If you replace that with [*a te*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23a%20te%23), that's 831 results, and 275 for [*abs te*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23abs%20te%23). Similarly, [*?ab me*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ab%20me%23) gives you only 1 result; it happens to be from Cicero, but I suspect it to be an error in transcription.

So it is possible that no author *never* uses **ab te* or *?ab me*; but in certain common combinations *ab* is still extremely rare in almost all authors, and so it would be considered very odd to always use *ab*.

A few more queries:

- http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ab+bon
- http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ab+bello
- http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ab+ven

Comment: Interesting. Even *ab b-* gets a total of only two matches, and it looks like *ab p-*, *ab m-*, *ab g-* are all disfavored relative to the alternatives with *a*.

Comment: @TKR: Yeah, somehow they really didn't like *ab* before certain letters or letter combinations. Cf. also *a n-* versus *ab n-*.

Comment: Avoiding a double "b" makes perfect sense. Much like English only uses "an" before vowels, otherwise "a".

Answer (score 9):

[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dab) provide some guidance on the limitations of the pre-consonant use of *ab*:

> [*ab*] has become the principal form and the one most generally used through all periods—and indeed the only one used before all vowels and *h*; here and there also before some consonants, particularly *l*, *n*, *r*, and *s*; rarely before *c*, *j*, *d*, *t*; and almost never before the labials *p*, *b*, *f*, *v*, or before *m*.

So the use of *ab* before consonants can be summarized:

- Sometimes: *l*, *n*, *r*, *s*
- Rarely: *c*, *j*, *d*, *t*
- Almost never: *p*, *b*, *f*, *v*, *m*

Answer (score 8):

[Here](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1374/1/6/186-190,657-661,1092-1096,1210-1214#6) is a relevant passage from the second-century (CE) grammarian Velius Longus:

> antiquos scimus et abs te dixisse: nos contenti sumus a te dicere. scimus ipsos et ab Lucio dixisse: nos observamus ut [ab] praeponatur his nominibus quae a vocali incipiunt, ut cum dicimus ab Olympo. non adsumitur autem haec b littera, quotiens nomina a consonante incipiunt, ut a Romulo.

"We know that the ancients also said *abs te*; we are content to say *a te*. We know that they also said *ab Lucio*; we observe the rule that *ab* is used before nouns that begin with a vowel, as when we say *ab Olympo*. But this letter *b* is not added whenever nouns begin with a consonant, as *a Romulo*."

As the other answers show, this rule is not completely true of the Latin of all periods, but Velius Longus at least thought it was true of his own time's usage.