# Why "ex nihilo" instead of "e nihilo"?

Tags: pronunciation, preposition, spelling

I was helping a friend earlier with an English-to-Latin translation and we started talking about the prepositions "a(b)" and "e(x)", which lose their consonant if the following word begins with one [or so I thought!].

So this got me thinking about the phrase "ex nihilo," as in the belief that the world was created from nothing. Why isn't the phrase "e nihilo" instead?

Comment: On personalised book-plates ***Ex Libris*** is more usual than *E Libris,* even when the name of the owner is not in Latin ( **L** of course is a semi-vowel )

Comment: Related: [Would it be good Classical Latin style to always use the preposition “ab” and never “ā”?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/104/12)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's actually not a rule. *ab* and *ex* *can* lose their consonant, but in fact it's far more common for them not to. Check out Lewis and Short's entries on them:

ex/e

> *ex* always before vowels, and elsewhere more frequent than *e*; e. g. in Cic. *Rep*. *e* occurs 19 times, but *ex* 61 times, before consonants—but no rule can be given for the usage; cf., e.g., *ex* and *e* together: “qui ex corporum vinculis tamquam e carcere evolaverunt,” Cic. *Rep*. 6, 14. But certain expressions have almost constantly the same form, as *ex parte*, *ex sententia*, *ex senatus consulto*, *ex lege*, *ex tempore*, etc.; but *e regione*, *e re nata*, *e vestigio*, *e medio*, and *e republica* used adverbially.

*ab/a* is more complicated, but you even see archaicisms like *abs te* very frequently. Same thing applies, though: *a* is used less often than *ab* before consonants. Nathaniel [in another thread](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1250/78) posted the relevant part of Lewis and Short concerning when you use *ab* and *a*:

> [ab] has become the principal form and the one most generally used through all periods—and indeed the only one used before all vowels and h; here and there also before some consonants, particularly l, n, r, and s; rarely before c, j, d, t; and almost never before the labials p, b, f, v, or before m.

Worth reading other posts in that thread, too.

Comment: I have also seen the usage controlled that way in text where a distinction is made between _"from"_ and _"out of"_ (as in exited from, or brought out of; similar to "from" I know but different enough to be distinct): from my experience contextually `e nihilo` would be likely to be from nothing and `ex nihilo` would be "out of nothing"