# Choosing between the prefixes e- and ex-

Tags: grammar-choice, prefix

Before a consonant on can use either version of the prepositions *e/ex*.
Both seem to appear in prefixes as well, but *ex-* is often assimilated.
It seems that, for example, words beginning with F take *ex-*: *efficere*, *efferre*, *effundere*…
On the other hand, words beginning with L take *e-*: *eligere*, *elevare*, *eloqui*…
My examples are verbs, but the pattern does not seem to be restricted to them.

This little observation suggests that some consonants (like L) require the prefix *e-* while others (like F) require *ex-*.
Which ones take *e-* and which ones *ex-*?
Are there perhaps consonants that can take either one?
Is there an easy way to memorize or understand the division to two consonant types?

Comment: Related question about the prepositions rather than the prefixes: [Why “ex nihilo” instead of “e nihilo”?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2430)

Comment: I suspect it has to do with whether the consonant following is voiced or unvoiced (we have *enervo, emendo, egredior* but *exsorbeo, expendo, extero*).

Comment: @JoelDerfner Good theory! I'll go through the consonants and see if it's true. If you have any ideas as to *why* it should be that way, please write an answer. I have no clue, other than it sounds better that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through all Latin consonants.
All consonants seem to prefer only one of *e-* and *ex-*.
I have only listed one example per consonant.
There are no (or only few and rare) verbs starting with X or Z.

The prefix *e-*:

- B: *(e)bibere*
- D: *(e)ducere*
- G<sup>1</sup>: *(e)gerere*
- I<sup>2</sup>: *(e)iurare, eicere < iacere*
- L: *(e)loqui*
- M<sup>3</sup>: *(e)mergere*
- N: *(e)numerare*
- R<sup>4</sup>: *(e)rumpere*
- V<sup>5</sup>: *(e)vertere*

The prefix *ex-*:

- C: *(ex)cedere*
- F: *(ef)ferre*
- P: *(ex)pellere*
- Q: *exquirere < quaerere*
- S<sup>6</sup>: *(ex)secare*
- T: *(ex)tollere*

---

<sup>1</sup>
L&S mentions *exgurgitare* as a synonym of *egurgitare*.
I found no other such verbs.

<sup>2</sup>
I only included the consonantal I (or J).
For vocalic I the prefix is *ex-*: *ire > exire*.

<sup>3</sup>
L&S mentions *exmovere* as a synonym of *emovere*.
Otherwise *e-* is always used before M.

<sup>4</sup>
L&S mentions *exradicare* as a synonym of *eradicare*.
There is also a rare *exrogare*.

<sup>5</sup>
I only included the consonantal V.
For vocalic U (or V) the prefix is *ex-*: *urere > exurere*.

<sup>6</sup>
The *exs-* can become *ex-*; consider *existere < sistere*.

---

Conclusion:
**Voiced consonants take the prefix *e-*, unvoiced ones take *ex-*.
There are very few exceptions.**
I have no idea why this is the way it is, other than it sounds more natural this way.
See TKR's comment below for an explanation.

Comment: This rule is part of a larger pattern: Latin generally disallows *s* before a voiced consonant, and historically such an *s* was lost, along with any consonant that immediately preceded it, and with compensatory lengthening of the preceding vowel. For example, *vēlum* 'sail' < *wekslom, *āla* 'wing' < *aksla, *trēdecim* '13' < *trēsdekim. It's thought that in such cases the [s] first became [z] by voicing assimilation and later was lost.