# Syllabifying S into an onset?

Tags: phonology, scansion, old-latin

Someone recently called my attention to a hexameter by Lucilius:

> Jānus, Quirīnus "pater" siet ac dicātur ad ūnum.
> *Janus or Quirinus may be "father"; every single [god] is called this.*

And there's something a bit odd about this scansion. The second syllable of *Jānus* has to scan as light, even though it's followed by another consonant. In other words, the final *-s* before a stop isn't treated as a coda.

This makes sense to me—phonologically, *squ-* is a valid syllable onset, as in *squālor*. But I've never seen this sort of syllabification in metered poetry before: normally, *s* between a vowel and a consonant is treated as a coda (e.g. *-us la-* in Aeneid I.2).

How common is this? Does it happen in Classical authors too (or really anyone except Lucilius)? And is there a name for it?

Comment: This has actually been answered before: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/3050/78

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard analysis of this phenomenon, which shows up in Early or Old Latin poets such as Lucilius and Plautus, is that word-final *s* was not resyllabified, but rather prone to elision when followed by a consonant (but not when followed by a vowel). Thus, some modern editors choose to omit the letter S and replace it with an apostrophe in such cases. Words whose final *s* was historically derived from a geminate, such as *es* (< *es-s) and *mīles* (<*mīless < *mīlet-s) usually are not scanned short in this manner.

The light scansion of a word-final sequence of short vowel + *s*  can occur regardless of whether the *s* can form a valid onset cluster with the following consonant(s). For example, "[The Problem of the Omission of Word-final -s as Evidenced in Latin Inscriptions](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/sites/default/files/pdf/137621.pdf)", Adamik 2017 (page 13) cites the following example from Adams (2013: p. 132): Ennius, Ann. 377: "nos sumu’ Romani, qui fuimus ante Rudini". Here we see short scansion even though /sr/ does not occur at the start of Latin words.

Some sources discussing this describe the condition for elision more specifically as "word-final *s* after a short vowel", but I don't see how we'd know whether it did or didn't also occur after a long vowel, since elision in that context wouldn't affect the meter. Michael Weiss apparently shares my skepticism about whether the loss of  word-final /s/ was conditioned by the length of the preceding vowel:

> I don’t think we *can* be sure that final *-s* had a different treatment after long vowels than after short vowel.  There can be no metrical evidence as far as I can see.  Further non-notation of final *-s* after a long vowel (see Vine 1993:22) is found in inscriptions at Rome, and not just dialectically—and incidentally
> Latin inscriptions from the 3rd century are more commonly found outside of Rome.

([OHCGL Addenda and Corrigenda](https://www.academia.edu/1197863/Outline_of_the_Historical_and_Comparative_Grammar_of_Latin), p. 10)

Comment: Interesting! Do you have an example where it doesn't form a valid onset?