# How to translate "evaluate"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, verbs, mathematics

In mathematics people say that

> Evaluate *f* at *x*

What word in Latin means "evaluate"? The construction *ex-valor-are* -> *evaloro, -are, -avi, -atum* seems to be an analogue but I am not sure if this makes sense, and I don't see it used anywhere.

> Evalora *f* in *x*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!
First, *valor* seems to be indeed a good word for "value" in the sense of mathematics and computer science.
It appears in Newton's [Philosophiae naturalis principia mathematica](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Philosophiae_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica_-_DE_MOTU_CORPORUM_LIBER_SECUNDUS._-_SECT._II._De_motu_corporum_quibus_resistitur_in_duplicata_ratione_velocitatum.) and is also used by [Gauss](http://thelatinlibrary.com/gauss.html).

However, I found no hits for a verb containing *-valor-*.
We may need to coin a new verb; I will discuss the reasons for this at the end.
The easiest way out is to borrow the English word, since ***evaluare*** fits Latin very well.
But this doesn't feel quite right to me, as the originally Latin word *valor* has been changed after borrowing to French.
A similar verb can be derived within Latin.

No Romance language seems to use anything with *valor* for this verb, but the verbs are related.
Italian seems to be *valutare*, Spanish *evaluar*, and French *évaluer*, for example.
The simplest Latin verb seems to be ***valorare***, and this is my first suggestion.
(The word *valor* itself comes from *valere*, but for this purpose I think it is best to derive from *valor* instead of the underlying verb. The noun *valor* in this use is abstracted from the meaning of *valere*.)

It is possible to and a prefix.
Since [the verb starts with V, it should be *e-* instead of *ex-*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2466/79).
This prefix can be used to emphasize that the action is carried out completely (cf. *efficere* or *ebibere*), and this sense is appropriate — although not strictly necessary.
As the Romance examples above show, the prefix may or may not be present in daughter languages.
If such a prefix is used, then the natural choice is ***evalorare***.

The different options have different pros and cons.
For anyone who has studied mathematics or programming in English, *evaluare* is easy to understand without much thought.
However, it does sound somewhat non-Latin.
The most Latin option to my ear is *valorare*, but it is further away from other languages.
The middle ground between these is *evalorare*.
My suggestion is *valorare*, but there is no canonical correct choice as far as I know.
Your suggestion of *evalorare* sounds legitimate, too.

I have found no attestations for these three options.
But this is not really surprising; the abstraction level of evaluation (as opposed to using simply the word "value" in some way) seems to have arisen only after Latin fell out of fashion in science.
I would be thrilled to see examples, but there might not be any.
When it comes to contemporary use, there is no council to decide on the correct terminology, and if there is too little precedent to establish a rule, you are free to choose anything reasonable.

Lastly, let me point out that my purpose was to find a verb that would be comfortable to use for a modern scientist who happens to know Latin.
If I were to write lecture notes on functional analysis and distribution theory in Latin and wanted to define an evaluation functional, I would pick one of these three verbs to evaluate with.
Any kind of elegance or classical precedent, while great, is secondary.
For a different perspective, you'll have to ask someone else.

Comment: Non sure, but I suspect you need a workaround to say both _evaluate_ and _function_ in proper scientific Latin. A quick lookup in the _principia_ gave lots of _equatio_, _inveniri_, _computatio_, etc. in places evaluate and function would have fitted.

Comment: @Rafael That would depend on your definition of proper scientific Latin. Perhaps I should have made it clearer in the answer (I'll edit), but I'm aiming for something that would feel natural to a modern scientist who happens to know Latin, leaving classical or otherwise high style as a secondary goal. Newton's language might feel a little awkward in today's use. Gauss doesn't seem to shy away from *functio*, so I wouldn't either.

Comment: Allright. By scientific Latin I meant broadly which was used in science at the time it was the language of science. I'm no expert in it at all, and spoke out of intuition only. I'm actually relieved to know Gauss used _functio_!

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta Looking at it slightly differently, I would use something like _vim_ or _significationem_ with _subducere_, 'drawing out the force / significance'. Might not this better represent the meaning — and in classical Latin?

Comment: @TomCotton *Vim subducere* sounds like a good classical way to put it. However, I would not use such a phrase in technical use when a derivative like *valorare* is available. The problem is partly the ambiguity of terms, since *vis* and *subducere* could mean so many other things. It might have the correct meaning, but perhaps not the convenience of use. The best translation of "evaluate" depends very heavily on the exact goal, much more than with everyday language. Cicero might indeed translate "value" as *vis*, but I would not. I admit to being strongly biased as a modern mathematician.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta I agree completely, which is why I offered just a comment, rather than an answer!