# Translation: Out of my death, new life

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, declension, motto, genitive

I took a Latin course a few years ago, and now I'm trying my hand for a friend's tattoo.

Is my translation of the title correct?

English: Out of my death, new life.

Latin attempt: *Ex mei mortis novae vitae*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial version is quite good! There are just a few case errors.

*Ex* (or *ē* if you prefer) takes the ablative case, which here would be *morte meā*. And the "new life" should be in the nominative case: *vīta nova*.

I'm not entirely sure whether the Romans would say "my death" (*mors mea*, ablative *morte meā*) or "the death of me" (*mors meī*, ablative *morte meī*). But the idiom *morte suā morī* "to die one's own death" (i.e, die of natural causes) makes me think *mea*. [I asked a new question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7075/406) to be sure.

If you want a full sentence, you can also add the word *venit* "…comes" at the end, but this isn't necessary for a short saying or epigram.

All in all, my version would be:

> Ex/ē morte meā, vīta nova [venit].

Unfortunately there aren't quite enough syllables to rearrange into a hexameter line, or even a pentameter.

The nouns and adjectives can be freely rearranged; I prefer to have each adjective following its respective noun, but especially in poetry you can mix up the words as much as you like (so long as *ex/ē* comes before *morte*) and it'll still be understood.

Similarly, [the choice between *ex* and *ē* is purely stylistic](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2431/406), as is the decision to include or leave off the macrons (marks over long vowels). I prefer *ex* and including macrons, but that's nothing more than a personal preference.

Comment: This is my opinion only, but think I macrons simply look wrong outside of their use in dictionaries and teaching materials.  For a tattoo, I would definitely avoid them.  Otherwise, I agree with your response.

Comment: @varro Completely fair; I like them because the ambiguity of leaving them off gets under my skin, so I include them whenever possible. But leaving them off is certainly in no way wrong!