# Mors mea or mors meī?

Tags: pronouns, genitive, possessive-pronouns, personal-pronouns

If I wanted to talk about "the death of Caesar", I wouldn't think twice about using the genitive (*mors Caesaris*). But if you asked me what sort of genitive this is—possessive, partitive, or objective—I wouldn't be able to tell you.

These distinctions seldom actually matter in practice, but there's one important case when they do: [with personal pronouns](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/when-to-use-a-genitive-pronoun-instead-of-a-possessive-adjective). The possessive genitive uses the form *meus/tuus -a -um*, while all other genitives use the form *meī/tuī*.

In particular, would "my death" be *mors mea*, or *mors meī*? Equivalently, would "your death" be *mors tua*, or *mors tuī*?

This came up in [the translation of a tattoo](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7073/406).

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/when-to-use-a-genitive-pronoun-instead-of-a-possessive-adjective

Comment: @brianpck Yep, I actually linked that one in the question! That one's about when to use *meī* with a possessive/subjective, though, while this one's about whether a specific instance counts as possessive/subjective or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another use of the genitive that you've left out is subjective genitive, which is what this is. These are discussed in, e.g., Gildersleeve and Lodge, *Latin grammar* §363. Allen and Greenough, *New Latin grammar* §243, Note 1 treats them, not unreasonably, as a species of possessive genitive (where what is 'owned' is an action or state of being).

Death implies the action of dying, and Caesar is the one who performs that action here; he's like the subject. For the personal pronouns (1st person, 2nd person, and 3rd person reflexive), subjective relations, like possessive relations, use the possessive adjectives. So 'my death' = *mors mea*.

Answer (score 4):

An unlearned but hopefully useful answer. Searching a large corpus of texts gives:

- *mors mea*: [2,612 hits](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22mors%20mea%22;a=srchls)
- *mors mei*: [26 hits](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22mors%20mei%22;a=srchls;lmt=all&facet=language008_full:%22Latin%22)
- *mors tua*: [4,821 hits](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22mors%20tua%22;a=srchls&facet=language008_full:%22Latin%22)
- *mors tui*: [80 hits](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22mors%20tui%22;a=srchls&facet=language008_full:%22Latin%22)
- *mors sua*: [969 hits](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22mors%20sua%22;a=srchls&facet=language008_full:%22Latin%22)
- *mors sui*: [49 hits](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22mors%20sui%22;a=srchls&facet=language008_full:%22Latin%22)

As brianpck pointed out in the comments, the low number of hits for the *mei* and related cases does not necessarily mean that this is a valid case. As he points out, these two words could appear in a different grammatical sense, e.g. with *mei* being an adjective and not a pronoun, which is the sole interest of the question. I'm still of the opinion that the dramatic difference in occurrence is helpful as supportive evidence to cnread's answer (and not alone).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is problematic on two levels: (1) the search results aren't filtered to just Latin, (2) more to the point, I guarantee that 99% (if not 100%) of the *mei/tui/sui* results are possessive *adjectives*, not *pronouns.* For instance, the first Latin result for *mors mei* reads *mors **mei praesulis***.

Comment: @brianpck (1) solved. I made the proportions even stronger though. Regarding (2), even if filtering for pronouns case only, would the huge differences in hits make the answer to reverse very unlikely?

Comment: My point was actually that the huge difference should be even more huge (i.e. verging on 0 hits) for pronouns used in this way. In other words, *mors mei* means "the death of my...", not "the death of me."

Comment: @brianpck But surely that, in this purely statistical method, wold be evidence enough that _mea_ is the common/correct term?

Comment: Correct, but it's very easy to interpret this answer as giving evidence that "mors mei" is uncommon but admissible, when in fact it is never used for "my death."

Comment: @brianpck oh, I understand now. Yes, you are totally correct on that. I will update to point this out.